# How to remove 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text:' from message and text

Tags: c#, system, message

I have written a simple program in C# in which

1. messages are displayed using a statement like:

```
    {
     MessageBox.Show("Enter the Correct Values. ", "Error", 
                     MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
     return;
    }
```

1. Some text box contents are written to text files using StreamWriter.
   In both case, in addition to the correct content, I also get the prefix:
   System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text:
2. I get a similar prefix (and a suffix of \r\n) when using StreamReader to read the contents of a text file.

How do I avoid this?

Comment: Post some code. Sounds like your calling `ToString()` on an object where you shouldn't be.

Answer (score 7):

Without seeing your code, I'm guessing you're passing the `TextBox` directly to the `StreamWriter`, rather than passing the `TextBox.Text` property value.  Passing the `TextBox` reference directly to `StreamWriter.WriteLine` will call `TextBox.ToString()` to get a string value that it can write, and it looks like `TextBox.ToString()` is generating that prefix.  Pass in `TextBox.Text`, and you shouldn't see it anymore.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.  You should click the check next to this answer to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest soloution to this i have ever found is to split the string and use the required string

```
        string str = TextBox1.Text;
        char[] spearator = { ' ' };
        String[] splitStr = str.Split(spearator);
        string RequiredString =  splitStr[1];
```

Try this code hope this will work